# What is kumafarre?

Tags: danganronpa-v3-killing-harmony

"kumafarre" is a pretty prominent part of Case 6. [This extremely spoilerrific bit of gameplay shows kumafarre pretty clearly.](https://youtu.be/poTc_5urQOU?t=7690) However, the meaning of "kumafarre" is not acknowledged in any point during the game (that I could find).

What is "kumafarre"? Is it some portmanteau of monoKUMA and... uh... something else?

---

> Please expect spoilers for the entire game series in the comments and answers below.

Comment: Kuma means [**bear**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bear) in Japanese. No idea what "farre" means, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a reference to the [Nicofarre](http://nicofarre.jp) night club. The place was originally called Velfarre, before it shut down and was reopened by Nico Nico, the japanese equivalent of YouTube; hence its new name, Nicofarre. Since this is Monokuma's Nicofarre, we end up with Kumafarre.

As for why this club in particular is referenced, [this article](https://kotaku.com/5822507/legendary-japanese-club-reborn-with-trolling) makes it pretty clear:

> As blog Asajin points out, Nicofarre has five LED wallscreens that can project comments into the crowd. That is, people can comment during a concert, and said comment should appear on a screen in the club.
>
> [image: A shot of nicofarre that is very reminiscent of Trial 6]
>
> Source: [Legendary Japanese Club Reborn with Trolling — Kotaku](https://kotaku.com/5822507/legendary-japanese-club-reborn-with-trolling)

Comment: Many thanks to [this 5ch poster *(potentially nsfw ads)*](https://krsw.5ch.net/test/read.cgi/handygame/1487488150/960) for spilling the beans.